# JavaScript frame / change the background color of html elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am developing a plugin, which is used to change the background color / frame of the html elements following a click on a button (page link).

If you click on a button of the 1st menu, the 2nd menu sent will be framed in all the pages (i.e. even after loading the page, it remains framed).

```js
    //select elements ( button)
    var pElt5 = document.querySelectorAll("button");



    //changebackground
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $(pElt).click(function(){
      $(this).addClass("border1");});
    });
```

I already have a css file which contains all the classes (border1, ...).

The problem is that while clicking on the button, the background color changes instantly, but does not remain in all the website pages (e.g when the page loads again after clicking on a link, the color change disappears)

Comment: I think you have to save this settings somewhere, for example in local or session storage.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to page to remember what background colour was selected, you will have to store that information somewhere in the clients browser. Such as in `cookies` or `localStorage`.

Then when the page is reloaded, you can check for that and display the correct background accordingly.